# Movie Editor Masking Animate change?

Tags: animation, masking

So I have animated a mask for video editing, and then for whatever reason, the video changed to where the video had the same frame for 2 frames. So the mask is 1 frame offset in the middle of the animation. Is there a way to fix this? Or perhaps a way to change the mask animation in nla or something?

Comment: @cegaton Mask keyframes can be adjusted in the dope sheet by changing it's mode to 'Mask'.

Comment: Seems to me you are using some kind of compressed video... mpeg and mp4s will sometimes decode differently and you'll get those repeated (or missing) frames. Avoid formats that use long GOP compression in the future. A possible fix for your problem is to export your video as an image sequence, making sure you don't have those repeated frames, and apply your masks to the sequence in the compositor.

Comment: Thanks to both of you guys for your amazing insights! It helped a lot!